# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

[Moderator election #1](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Programming Language Design and Implementation has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Alexis King]

[image: lyxal]

[image: Michael Homer]

They will be forming [the first mod team](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) for Programming Language Design & Implementation — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6155429158584320).

Comment: Congratulations to Alexis, lyxal, and Michael. I'm sure they will do the best. **Best wishes to you!**

Answer (score 19):

## Congratulations to Alexis, lyxal, and Michael!

I have no doubt that all three of you will be excellent moderators, and (hopefully) help the site all the way to graduation!